# Infinite read from java socket(windows)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

simple code

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("utf-8")));
while (true) {
    int ch = reader.read();
    if(ch==-1){
        break;
    }
}
```

sometime it stuck , because reader return ffff. any idea how to find reason?? look like some memory corruption in jvm. but reproduced only in java 8 on windows 2012. `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read() The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.`
problem: read never return -1. even client socket is closed

Comment: first read topic question and do not link on random java topics ;)

Comment: @gusto2 I am unable to understand what you are talking about. The OP has posted code, and I don't see any answer in your link that applies to this problem. Please keep it relevant and constructive.

Comment: As you have already mentioned in another comment, it looks like the client keeps reading EOF/EOS -1 value. In one of the answers of the linkwd post should be a snippet of working code (I did not test myself). So I assume the problem of @kain is in incorrect declaration or cast.

Comment: And now I see the linked post uses byte type (what is wrong, but working for ASCII). So as you already @EJP wrote, casting to int is a must.

Answer (score 0):

> sometime it stuck, because reader returns ffff

This code does not get 'stuck' at all, let alone because the reader returned 0xffff. It returns any char in the range 0..0xffff, all of which is data, not a problem, or -1 at end of stream.

The problem here is that when `read()` returns -1, i.e. 0xffffffff, you are storing it into a `char`, so its value *becomes* 0xffff, which doesn't compare equal to -1, because it isn't, so you *loop* forever at end of stream. Not 'get stuck'.

`ch` needs to be declared as `int`.

Comment: Hi, I fixed code in example. it just some pseudo code. problem: read never return -1. even client socket is closed

Comment: And that is for the reason I stated.

Comment: hm sorry I missing something. ch declared as int. ffff is 65535. int -1 should be readed without problem :(

Comment: Not shown in your post. This problem is caused by declaring `ch` as a `char`.

Comment: So why would this code get 'stuck ' if the reader returned 0xffff?

Comment: this is the question: looks like some memory corruption. reader read gigabytes from closed socket, very strange. maybe some new jvm setting or etc?

Comment: You can't read gigabytes from a. closed socket. It is exactly as I said. You failed to recognize end of stream because of the elementary coding error I have mentioned in this answer, and are now spinning mindlessly at EOS.

Comment: Question is.. Isn't the server sending 0xFF in the loop?

Comment: The server can send anything it likes. The only way 0xff, or rather 0xffff, can possibly present a problem with this code is if you try to store the result of `read()` into a `char` instead of an `int`, for the reason I stated. *Ergo* that is what you must be doing. There is still no evidence that this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Wait :) code is: int ch = reader.read(); not char/byte/etc this is not a casting problem. Issue often reproduced on Amazon cloud servers 2012. Something wrong with socket buffer. 1 more thing. If issue is reproduced and I do socket  close, than all other sockets in process throw read error. And I can't reopen socket during X seconds.(probably GC clean something..)

Comment: Something wrong with your code. 0xffff, or 0x or wherever it is today, does not 'block' anything. Nothing 'wrong with socket buffer' for anybody else. Only you.